# Using after_find callback to overwrite nil values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Right now I have a Rails 3 model for storing profile data. One of the columns in that database table contains an image url if the user chooses to display a profile picture (this also integrates with the Facebook Graph API to store the user's profile picture url if they login with Facebook but that's irrelevant). The problem I am having is that when the image column is nil, I need a way to set it to a default path on my server. Please note that I cannot use a default value in a migration or model here. My thought was to use an after_find but the following is not working:

In Profile Model:

```
  def after_find
    if self.image.nil?
      self.image = "/assets/generic_profile_image.png"
    end
  end
```

In view (HAML):

```
.profile_pic
    = image_tag @user.profile.image
```

The Profile model is linked to a User model via a has_one association. Right now instead of dynamically turning the image attribute into "/assets/generic_profile_image.png", it seems to do nothing leaving me with the following generated code on my page:

```
    <div class='profile_pic'>
      <img alt="Assets" src="/assets/" />
    </div>
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. A conditional in the view is out of the question as the profile image is shown in way too many places!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is your after_find callback ins't actually getting called. You need to define it this way:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_find :update_image

  def update_image
    if self.image.nil?
      self.image = "/assets/generic_profile_image.png"
    end
  end
end
```

Now everything should work fine.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Must have been sleeping when I wrote the aforementioned code.

Answer (score 3):

Just make the condition in the model and reference it in the view.

```
class User
  delegate :image, :to => :profile, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => true

  def picture_url
    if profile_image.present?
      profile_image
    else
      "/assets/generic_profile_image.png"   
    end
  end
end
```

I like this approach because you won't have to run a sql query when you want to change the default picture.

I added the delegate to prevent breaking the law of demeter.

Of course you've already guessed the view code:

```
.profile_pic
    = image_tag @user.picture_url
```

Comment: I like this method and I'll definitely try it!